# How can I do a custom GET with restangular which returns data for a CSV?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, restangular

I have a problem here that I'm trying to solve but without success...
Is there a way to do a custom GET with restangular where I can pass a format (.csv) and pass parameters, then get data that I can pass to a Blob to download a csv?

All types of requests that I tried returned an object, like this:

```
factory.getCsv = function (params, page, headers) {
  return this._base.all('enrollments.csv')
                   .getList(params, headers);
};
```

This returns an object, but when I pass it to a Blob class in Javascript, I can't use is to create a csv downloadable file.

It returns an object that doesn't have any info about the response, only a restangularCollection. Any hints?

Thanks